# Can someone help me to formulate a question?

Tags: discussion

I tried to ask a question about why the SBC haven't fired their "ethics" spokesman, but gave up because I found it too difficult to phrase the question. If anyone feels up to [creating a question on this](http://timothy.green.name/links/sbc-ethics-and-racism/), I'd be interested.

The answer I'm seeing mentioned in various places is that the SBC is a vile institution which wouldn't recongnise an ethical statement if it jumped up and bit them on the bum, and that a racist bigot is a perfect fit to be their spokesman. This may very well be the case, but I assume some people might disagree.

Answer (score 5):

I think the problem with "Why hasn't Organization X done Y?" is that it

1. Would be (rightly) closed as Too Localized.
2. Is impossible to really answer. How are we to know the mind of Organization X?

That said, I think you could still salvage a question out of there. Set the context with that localized situation as an example, but ask an objective question. Something like:

> Person Z, spokesman for Organization X, has said Y. X's beliefs are as
>   follows: A, B, C.
>
> Is Y compatible with A, B, or C? Should Christian organizations fire
>   their employees when they say things incompatible with their beliefs?
>   How incompatible do those things have to be?

Answer (score 1):

So, I actually had Richard Land for dinner when I was in college. Thought he was a bit pompous, but he is really, really smart. As a former Baptist, I can tell you the real reason he hasn't been censured is that he doesn't report to anybody. As head of the Religious Liberty Commission, his committe reports to the Convention - but the convention only meets once a year. In short, there is simply nobody who could took any action against him.

Comment: how exactly does this answer the "help me formulate a question" request? Shouldn't it be a comment? :)